# Framework not working in one of my targets (a screensaver)

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, frameworks

I've an XCode Swift project with 2 targets, an traditional app and a screensaver. I want to use a framework in both (I've tried with at least 2 frameworks with no luck).

In the app they work ok but in the screensaver, despite that I'm able to compile (I have a bridging file with the appropriate importe and I have the framework copied and linked)

[image]

when the screensaver runs it crash with this error in Console:

```
Jul  1 16:33:15 ironbird.local ScreenSaverEngine[60006]: Error loading /Users/juanjo/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver/Contents/MacOS/Ninja:  dlopen(/Users/juanjo/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver/Contents/MacOS/Ninja, 265): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Paddle.framework/Versions/A/Paddle
      Referenced from: /Users/juanjo/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver/Contents/MacOS/Ninja
      Reason: image not found
```

Can someone help me to solve the problem or at least to debug it? If I search for the error I find people that forgotten to either copy or link the framework, which is not my case.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** If I use install_name_tool to change the path where the image is looked for for a absolute path, I make the screensaver run.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work changing the original framework as this:

```
$ cd Frameworks/Paddle.framework/Versions/A/
$ install_name_tool -id @rpath/Paddle.framework/Versions/A/Paddle Paddle
```